# Prevent addition of a trailing slash to a URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, url, uri

I'm using the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL) API in my React Native application to conveniently construct query strings for my requests.

I found out that this API adds a trailing slash to the URL which breaks all the requests.

```
let uri = new URL('https://example.com/path');
console.log(uri.toString()); 
// https://example.com/path/
```

I made some tests in a browser (Chromium 87) and found out that this behavior is not present there. Is it a quirk of React or React Native?

The question is how can I prevent the addition of a trailing space to the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
uri.href
```

instead of `uri.toString()`